# Unable to pass login information through AJAX using Codeigniter MVC system

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

Good afternoon,

I'm looking for some advise on Codeigniter and getting an Ajax login form to work with my controller and upon being successfully logged in then to take me to a dashboard/homescreen for the particular user.

Here is my 'auth.php' Controller code:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('data_model');
    $this->load->database();
}

//** Check Status & Redirect To Login **//

public function index() {
    if($this->session->userdata('admin_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/dashboard', 'refresh' );
    else if($this->session->userdata('staff_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'staff/dashboard', 'refresh' );
    else if($this->session->userdata('client_login') == 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'client/dashboard', 'refresh' );

    $this->load->view('login');
}

//** Login Function **//

function ajax_login() {
    $response = array();

    //** Credentials of user login **//
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $response['submitted_data'] = $_POST;

    //** Validating the login **//
    $login_status = $this->validate_login($email, $password);
    $response['login_status'] = $login_status;
    if ($login_status == 'success') {
        $response['redirect_url'] = $this->session->userdata('last_page');
    }
}

//** Validating Credentials **//

function validate_login($email = '' , $password = '') {
    $credentials = array('email' => $email, 'password' => sha1($password));

    //** Checking Admin Credentials **//
    $query = $this->db->get_where('admin', $credentials);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_login', '1');
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_user_id', $row->admin_id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $row->name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_type', 'admin');
            return 'success';
    }
```

& here is my login.php view.

```
<div class="login-container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">

<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($)
                {
                    // Reveal Login form
                    setTimeout(function(){ $(".fade-in-effect").addClass('in'); }, 1);


                    // Validation and Ajax action
                    $("form#login").validate({
                        rules: {
                            email: {
                                required: true
                            },

                            password: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },

                        messages: {
                            email: {
                                required: 'Please enter your email.'
                            },

                            password: {
                                required: 'Please enter your password.'
                            }
                        },

                        // Form Processing via AJAX
                        submitHandler: function(form)
                        {                                                               
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "auth/validate_login",
                                method: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {
                                    do_login: true,
                                    email: $(form).find('#email').val(),
                                    password: $(form).find('#password').val(),
                                },
                                success: function(resp)
                                {
                                    show_loading_bar({
                                        delay: .5,
                                        pct: 100,
                                        finish: function(){

                                            // Redirect after successful login page (when progress bar reaches 100%)
                                            if(resp.accessGranted)
                                            {
                                                window.location.href = 'auth/index';
                                            }
                                                                                        else
                                            {
                                                toastr.error("You have entered wrong password, please try again. User and password is <strong>demo/demo</strong> :)", "Invalid Login!", opts);
                                                $passwd.select();
                                            }
                                                                                    }
                                    });

                                                                    }
                            });

                        }
                    });

                    // Set Form focus
                    $("form#login .form-group:has(.form-control):first .form-control").focus();
                });
            </script>

            <!-- Errors container -->
            <div class="errors-container">


            </div>

            <!-- Add class "fade-in-effect" for login form effect -->
            <form method="post" role="form" id="login" class="login-form fade-in-effect">

                <div class="login-header">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/logo@2x.png" alt="" width="80" />
                        <span>log in</span>
                    </a>

                    <p>Dear user, log in to access your user area!</p>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-dark" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-mask="email" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="passwd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-dark" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark  btn-block text-left">
                        Log In
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="login-footer">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>auth/forgot_password">Forgot your password?</a>

                </div>

            </form>
```

From the code above, I have declared a model but this doesn't actually contain any information as I have a get DB within my controller. Hopefully someone could shed some light on this.

Thank you!

Zak Hargreaves.

Comment: CodeIgniter is expecting the CSRF token value to be passed along with the  form data.  It's contained within a hidden form input that is automatically constructed when you use CodeIgniter's `form_open()` function.  Then when you do `ajax()`, you have to include the value of this hidden CSRF field.  Your browser console should be showing you some kind of error response to the `ajax()` request.

Comment: When I go into consoles and try and login, I usually get a POST ok, which is passed through to my controller - it's just not querying the DB - I feel i'm missing something. Any other help would be fantastic.

Comment: I took a closer look at your code and IMO ***you need to read the CodeIgniter documentation from start to finish***.  I'm not trying to be mean.  When I learned CI, I did the same thing... I read the manual completely and performed all of the included exercises, samples and tutorials.  It should only take you 3 or 4 hours to do everything.  What's wrong with your code?  Instead of using a CI Model to connect to your database, you're calling another function within your CI Controller.  This is completely wrong.  You would never have one Controller function calling another.

Comment: See:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: However, your root problem is that you are not outputting anything back to the `ajax()` function from your PHP.  You need to `echo` the response.

Comment: Afternoon Sparky, I've been through and I can see what you mean.  I shouldn't be calling ajax within my CI Controller; I also have another js file that is trying to carry out the same commands and getting confused.  I'll ready over the documentation and hopefully I can rectify this problem.  Many thanks,